# What should be the datatype of a sql table's column if we are inserting `NOW()` in the column

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to recreate the database that a particular java codebase works with locally. Here is a piece of sql statement I found in the codebase

```
sql="Insert into work(comid,alloc,type,priority,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6"
                + ",w,start,days) values("+comid+','+0+','+type+','+pri+','+m1+','+m2+','+m3+','+m4+','+m5+','+m6
                +','+r1+','+r2+','+r3+','+r4+','+r5+','+r6+','+w+','+"NOW()"+','+da+')';
```

I want to know if I want to create the `work` table locally what should be the datatype of the `start` column should it be varchar or some other special date type?

Comment: Please precise what type of database (mysql, postgresql, sql server...).

Comment: By the way both DATETIME and DATE fit

Comment: i am using mysql @Flo

Comment: This kind of scenario is highly syptomatic of poor schema design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the insertion time for the row, you can use a default value in MySQL:

```
create table t (
    . . ., 
    createdAt datetime default now()
);
```

If you do this, you don't need to insert the value at all.  The database will generate it.

Comment: So, the answer to the question is...?

Comment: @Strawberry . . . If you look carefully at the answer, you will see the answer . . . `datetime`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any of [the DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).
If you choose `date` however, only the date part of `now()` will be stored and not the time part, so instead you should use `current_date()`).
You could also (although there is no point to) use [CHAR and VARCHAR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/char.html) (like `char(19)` and `varchar(19)`).
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kEeDNocTTUfwt4xDEWbB8g/0).